# ¿Cómo hago que Python muestre radicales?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from math import sqrt


def bicuadradas(a, b, c):
    d = b**2 - 4 * a * c
    if d < 0:
        print("No tiene solución")
    elif d == 0:
        unos = -b / (2 * a)
        unos = sqrt(unos)
        print("Las únicas dos soluciones son {}".format(unos))
    else:
        dos = ((-b) + sqrt(d)) / (2 * a)
        dos2 = ((-b) - sqrt(d)) / (2 * a)

        if sqrt(d) <= 0:
            if dos > 0:
                dos = sqrt(dos)
                print("La solución es +{} y -{}".format(dos, dos))
            elif dos2 > 0:
                dos2 = sqrt(dos2)
                print("La solución es +{} y -{}".format(dos2, dos2))

        else:
            dos = sqrt(dos)
            dos2 = sqrt(dos)
            print("Las soluciones son +{}, -{}, +{} y - {}".format(dos, dos, dos2, dos2))

a = int(input("Dime el término de a: "))
b = int(input("Dime el término de b: "))
c = int(input("Dime el término de c: "))

bicuadradas(a, b, c)
```

Como supongo que sabréis, el resultado de una ecuación bicuadrada puede ser un radical.

El caso es que me gustaría que me mostrase un radical en lugar del número real. ¿Hay alguna forma?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Por *radical* te refieres a *"número complejo"*?

Answer (score 1):

Si he entendido bien, quieres buscar raices pero cuando la raiz cuadrada sea negativa que el resultado te devuelva valores complejos o (radicales, no me queda muy claro). En tu código existen varios problemas. Primero pones un `if` para los casos en los que la parte (el radicando) de la raíz cuadrada sea negativo. En el `else` vuelves a poner un caso para cuando sean negativos pero esa condición no se alcanzará nunca ya que se entraría en el primer `if`. Tu ejemplo modificado podría ser:

```
from math import sqrt
from cmath import sqrt as csqrt

def bicuadradas(a, b, c):
    d = b**2 - 4 * a * c
    if d < 0:
        x1 = ((-b) + csqrt(d)) / (2 * a)
        x2 = ((-b) - csqrt(d)) / (2 * a)
        print("La solución x1 es {}".format(x1))
        print("La solución x2 es {}".format(x2))
    elif d == 0:
        x = -b / (2 * a)
        print("Las única solución es {}".format(x))
    else:
        x1 = ((-b) + sqrt(d)) / (2 * a)
        x2 = ((-b) - sqrt(d)) / (2 * a)
        print("La solución x1 es {}".format(x1))
        print("La solución x2 es {}".format(x2))

a = int(input("Dime el término de a: "))
b = int(input("Dime el término de b: "))
c = int(input("Dime el término de c: "))

bicuadradas(a, b, c)
```

Por favor, comenta si eso resuelve tu problema o añade más información a tu pregunta para que podamos darte una mejor respuesta.

**[EDICIÓN]**

Después de alguna aclaración en los comentarios creo que lo siguiente igual te vale:

```
import sympy

def resolver(a, b, c):
    x = sympy.Symbol('x')
    expr = a * x**2 + b * x + c
    return sympy.solve(expr, x)
```

Si llamamos a la función `resolver` con `a=1; b=2; c=3`:

```
resolver(1,2,3)
```

El resultado sería:

```
[-1 - sqrt(2)*I, -1 + sqrt(2)*I]
```

¿Es esto lo que quieres?

Comment: No, con radical me refiero a que el output en lugar de mostrarme un número irracional (el resultado de una raíz) me muestre la raíz en sí, sin calcular.

Comment: Para hacer cálculo simbólico creo que sympy te puede ayudar. Cuando tenga 5 mins modifico el ejemplo usando sympy (en el móvil ahora).

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias, y no te preocupes, tómate tu tiempo para modificarlo, no tengo prisa.

Comment: He editado la respuesta. Mira a ver si así te funciona.